# How to change format of Warning admonition or add Caution in Sphinx HTML output

Tags: html, python-sphinx

This seems like it should be straightforward but I've been prowling the documentation and web and haven't found the answer.

I want to output HTML doc from Sphinx. Ideally I'd like to have three levels of "note" type highlighted text boxes. ReST defines several "admonitions": (http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#admonitions) but most of the Sphinx HTML themes include special formatting only for Note and Warning. (I am using one of the preinstalled themes, Classic.)

I have two questions:

1) How can I customize the color behind Warning in my documents?

2) How can I add a formatting style for Caution?

I see that these all end up with tags like `<div class="admonition warning"> ...` in the HTML output. But I can't find where the formatting for that class is defined. Is it in a stylesheet? Is it in a layout.html file or some other file?

Is there anything that explains how the various files in themes actually interact with each other? I haven't found a good primer. (I am no expert on css-based HTML either, so maybe that's part of the problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured out more and have a working workaround. (I'm still not sure how I'm supposed to handle this.)

Looks like my HTML code is reading directly from a few cascading stylesheets stored along with the output in a directory called _static. There's classic.css, which inherits from basic.css.

I don't understand how these relate to the files named like basic.css_t that live in the Python Sphinx install.

To change things, should I (A) try altering the _t files? or (B) create an altered local copy of classic.css that lives in my source directory?

If I go with B, more questions.

- Will it be overwritten by the values in the css_t template at build time? (I guess this is easy enough to test)
- Is it good practice to use the same filename for a modified version of that stylesheet?

Here's a workaround that avoids those questions and seems to be doing what I want - from this: https://github.com/snide/sphinx_rtd_theme/issues/117

- I created an override stylesheet that includes just the formatting I want to change.
- I stored it in the _static of my source directory.
- I defined it in my conf.py as follows:

  ```
  html_context = {
      'css_files': [
          '_static/theme_overrides.css', 
          ],
      }
  ```

Now, that github discussion said that this wasn't a solution for all kinds of themes (including the RTD theme mentioned in the question) but I think I'm safe for now.

What more should I know?