# How to create custom admonitions in custom directive sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, custom-directive

I have created a custom directive 'limitation' in Sphinx which mentions "Limitation" of a certain product. I want that the limitation be written within a colored box that is similar to 'note' or 'warning' directives with 'limitation' written as the title instead of 'note' or 'warning'. I want this to be handled by my custom directive 'limitation' itself.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change format of Warning admonition or add Caution in Sphinx HTML output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498027/how-to-change-format-of-warning-admonition-or-add-caution-in-sphinx-html-output)

Answer (score 3):

You can use admonition directly from Docutils:

```
 .. admonition:: Limitation

    Description of the limitations ...
```

Check http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html for more information.